# origin and first use of the word "comforter" when used to describe something worn around the neck?

Tags: etymology

What is the origin and first use of the word "comforter" when used to describe what, in the US, is known as a scarf?

Comment: OED's first citation for the "original" sense *One who or that which comforts or consoles* is 1382. They specifically list *A long woollen scarf worn round the throat as a protection from cold* with first citation 1823, which is rather odd considering their first citation for *A thing that produces physical comfort* isn't until until 1837 (the *comforter* in that example being a plaid blanket). I'd have expected those latter two to be the other way around. The baby's rubber dummy sense (primarily AmE) wasn't recorded until 1898.

Comment: FYI, in current U.S. usage, a "comforter" is generally a quilted blanket or bed-covering.

Answer (score 1):

On the origin of "comforter":

In Dutch, a 'komfoor' was used to keep things warm (foodstuffs, blacksmithing tools, heater, etc). With a lot of words in the English language originating from mainland Europe, I suspect 'comforter' comes from the same source. A quick check shows that 'komfoor'(spelled as 'caufoor' around 1300) comes from the [Latin](http://www.etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/komfoor) 'calefacere' via the French word 'chauffoir', both meaning as much as 'make warm'.

Comment: Well ... *comforter* [also](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=comfort&allowed_in_frame=0) comes from *comfort*, which comes from Late Latin *comfortare*. But it's quite possible that *comforter*s used to keep things warm originate from a merger of the English and Dutch words. (Or rather, from the Dutch word *comfoor* lending its meanings to the English word *comforter*.)

Comment: Hmm... I considered that, but with most explanations concerning confortare calling it 'courage' or 'consolation' (be or get strong with an emphasis on the mental aspect), I figured that even 'comfortable' came from 'calefacere', with the -able suffix originally coming from 'able to make or feel warm'. With no latin knowledge to speak of on my part, you are probably right.

Comment: Yes ... *comfort* originally meant *support* and *consolation* in English, but the meaning has changed since the 13th century. However, *comforter* used to mean a scarf or blanket doesn't really seem to come naturally from the previous English meanings (people, dogs, alcohol, tobacco pipes), so might easily have been influenced by the Dutch word.